# wrong number of arguments when using x, y arrays as pixel positions and z as colour value in matplotlib.pcolor()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have been trying to make a coloured image with a colourbar scale. Each pixel should correspond to colour bar values from the Z array, and x,y should be pixel position arguments (in mm) similar to this:
https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0010218014001989-gr6_lrg.jpg

Data is imported across many text files. However, a small example section of this input data can be recreated from the following code file to pandas dataframe code, (where the x axis range is -30 - 30mm (increment by 1) and y axis range is 6 - 15 mm (increment by 3):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

    x = np.linspace(-30,30,61)
    y = np.linspace(6, 15, 4)
    z = 1.35 * np.random.rand(61*4, 1)
    for i in range(0,3,1):
        x = np.append(x,x[:61])
    y = np.repeat(y,61)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['X [mm]'] = x
    df ['Y [mm]']  = y
    df['LDA1-Mean [m/s]'] = z
    print(df)
```

Now running the following code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    Z = df['LDA1-Mean [m/s]'].to_list()
    positions = np.array(list(zip(df['X [mm]'], df['Y [mm]'])))

    plt.pcolor(positions, Z)
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('solutions/graphs/test.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")
```

Produces the following error:
`TypeError: pcolor() takes 1 or 3 positional arguments but 2 were given`

Is there a better way to do this with imshow() or contourf(), I'm open to suggestions.

As the order of X and Y data cannot as consistent as, I'd prefer to take always use the X and Y position data rather than reordering Z data (and using only 1 argument).

Thank you in advance for the help - I am still new to programming. Please feel free to ask questions if there is something I have not explained.

Comment: `plt.pcolor` first wants a parameter with x, then one with y and then the Z "reshaped" to a 2D array (`Z.reshape(4, 31)`). Alternatively, `plt.imshow(Z.reshape(4, 31), extent=[-30,30,6,15])` should work.  Or, with the full x and y: `plt.tricontourf(df['X [mm]'], df['Y [mm]'], Z)`

Comment: Also note that you should call `savefig` before `plt.show` because `plt.show` erases the plot.

Comment: @JohanC that works perfectly, thank you so very much! Exactly what I needed.